# After validation jsf fails to reset values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

I have a jsf composite component implemented from two p:calendar components.
The idea is when the first calendar is selected, the value of the second calendar need to be reset. There is a problem when the validation takes place, and the reset of the second calendar is not performed.

After reading posts I decided to use EditableValueHolder in my validator.
I have custom validator:   in which I added the following code:

```
@Override

public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException {
//....
resetValues(fc);
}

public void resetValues(FacesContext fc) {
    PartialViewContext partialViewContext = fc.getPartialViewContext();
    Collection<String> renderIds = partialViewContext.getRenderIds();
    UIComponent input;
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = fc.getViewRoot();
    for (String renderId : renderIds) {
        input = viewRoot.findComponent(renderId);
        if (input.isRendered() && input instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
            EditableValueHolder editableValueHolder = (EditableValueHolder) input;
            editableValueHolder.setSubmittedValue(null);
            editableValueHolder.setValue(null);
            editableValueHolder.setValid(true);
            editableValueHolder.setLocalValueSet(false);
        }
    }
}
```

After debug I can see that each code line is passed, but nothing is happening on jsf side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right moment to reset the values. They will be overridden anyway for the current component after the `validate()` method leaves and also for the second calendar once it get validated. You need to perform the reset somewhere *after* the update model values phase, preferably before the invoke action phase, so that you've chance to change the model value in an action(listener) method. You could use an `ActionListener` or a `PhaseListener` for this.

By the way, the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a reuseable solution for this in flavor of [`ResetInputAjaxActionListener`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener).